# Print all entries after a pattern without including the pattern - awk

Tags: select, awk, printing, pattern-matching, multiple-columns

Consider the following input file

```
* Z1 Z2 A1pre A2pre A1post A2post I1pre I2pre I1gs I2gs Eexc1 Eexc2 n1 n2 TKEpre TKEpost  
* Z1: Atomic number of first fragment
* Z2: Atomic number of second fragment
* A1pre: Pre-neutron mass number of first fragment
* A2pre: Pre-neutron mass number of second fragment
* A1post: Post-neutron mass number of first fragment
* A2post: Post-neutron mass number of second fragment
* I1pre: Spin of first fragment after scission
* I2pre: Spin of second fragment after scission
* I1gs: Ground-state spin of first fragment
* I2gs: Ground-state spin of second fragment
* Eexc1: Excitation energy of first fragment [MeV]
* Eexc2: Excitation energy of second fragment [MeV]
* n1: Prompt neutrons emitted from first fragment
* n2: Primpt neutrons emitted from second fragment
* TKEpre: Pre-neutron total kinetic energy [MeV]
* TKEpost: Post-neutron total kinetic energy [MeV]

* Calculation with nominal model parameters
 38 54  97 138  94 136  5.5  9.0  0.0  0.0  21.72  14.78  3  2 159.43 156.00 
 39 53 101 134  99 133  2.5  4.0  2.5  3.5  17.12  12.93  2  1 166.45 161.75 
 36 56  92 143  91 143  3.0 11.5  2.5  2.5  12.27   7.81  1  0 170.00 168.44 
 38 54  93 142  92 141  3.5  7.0  0.0  2.5  13.94   9.81  1  1 168.95 163.96 
 40 52  99 136  98 135  2.5  6.0  0.0  3.5   9.28  13.10  1  1 177.04 172.75 
 40 52 100 135  98 134  0.0  6.5  0.0  0.0  14.74  10.13  2  1 176.61 173.55
```

What I want to do is to print specific columns following the `Calculation with nominal model parameters` pattern.

So far I've tried

```
awk '{/Calculation with nominal model parameters/;line=FNR}{for(i=0;i<=NR-19;++i){getline;print $5 "\t" $6 "\t" $16 "\t" $16*$6/($5+$6) "\t" $16*$5/($5+$6)}}{print line}' input
```

and my output is more or less what I want

```
88      144     159.10  98.7517 60.3483
87      146     164.87  103.309 61.5609
92      141     163.96  99.2204 64.7396
98      135     172.75  100.091 72.6588
98      134     173.55  100.24  73.3099
98      134     173.55  100.24  73.3099
19
```

As you can see the two last lines are identical. My goal is to avoid calculating the same thing twice. To achieve that I thought that I should finish the loop after `NR-NFR_pattern`, that's why I used `line` variable.

The weird thing is that even if I hardcode the pattern's `NFR` I don't get the desired output.

The weirdest thing is that if I replace the hardcoded `NFR` with the variable that has the `NFR` information i.e.

```
awk '{/Calculation with nominal model parameters/;line=FNR}{for(i=0;i<=NR-line;++i){getline;print $5 "\t" $6 "\t" $16 "\t" $16*$6/($5+$6) "\t" $16*$5/($5+$6)}}' input
```

I get the error

> `awk: (FILENAME=input FNR=2) fatal: division by zero attempted`

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  The output you provided doesn't match the input sample.  In title you say you want to print all lines after the pattern, however it looks like you want to print based on line number?

Comment: @karakfa : The line number should be constant. However I was trying to find a more universal and general solution.

Comment: And the general solution you're looking for is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing, I think, is that getline *changes* NR:

```
getline               Set $0 from next input record; set NF, NR, FNR, RT.
```

I wouldn't use getline at all.

```
awk 'isdata{print $5 "\t" $6 "\t" $16 "\t" $16*$6/($5+$6) "\t" $16*$5/($5+$6)}
  /Calculation with nominal model parameters/{isdata="yes"}' input
```

I get:

```
94      136     156.00  92.2435 63.7565
99      133     161.75  92.7274 69.0226
91      143     168.44  102.936 65.5044
92      141     163.96  99.2204 64.7396
98      135     172.75  100.091 72.6588
98      134     173.55  100.24  73.3099
```